# Can't Boot Ubuntu on Lenovo Ideapad 100s

Tags: boot, live-usb, ideapad

I just bought a Lenovo Ideapad 100s, and it's preloaded with Windows 10 Home Edition. The software on the computer doesn't allow me to access the boot menu to boot from the USB. Do any of you know a method to force the boot from the USB?

Comment: @Tony Lancer What gave that impression? It says * preloaded with Windows 10 Home Edition.*

Comment: @CelticWarrior That's embarrassing. :/ Need to fix my eyes.

Comment: Did you try Advanced Startup Options in Windows? It sometimes displays external, bootable devices.

Comment: @Michael Maynard - Any X86 or X86_64 allows access to BIOS/UEFI and also has an independent one time boot menu. Check this manual (pg. 14): https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad_100_15_ibd_ug_en_201602.pdf (probably not for your exact model but the method should be the same. You can also access it directly by Windows 10 as commented above.

Comment: I thought Lenovo locked down the BIOS so you couldn't install anything else on it. Maybe I heard wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I, you can access the BOOT menu by F12, or with the NOVO button right the battery indicator.
Note that this PC is 32bit UEFI only, so you had to include bootia32.efi file in the BOOT folder in your USB drive. Here the precompiled file: https://github.com/hirotakaster/baytail-bootia32.efi.
The state of the art is that you can achieve WIFI working patching the kernel, see https://plus.google.com/+IanMORRISON works to get a custom ubuntu ISO (Wifi, in the latest, work out of the box). For the audio, check the merge in Linux-next and Linux 4.9, changes are working in the shadows ;)

Answer (score 0):

next of Power Button there is small button. Switch off your Laptop, and press and hold this button you will see the bios menu where you can choose boot order, repair drive and enter to a full version of setup.
it is a great laptop for starbucks working

Answer (score -1):

Press F12 at boot time, select USB drive, and boot it in UEFI mode. Or, your computer does not support syslinux.